# multiple endpoints with same token in AWS SNS

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I am using AWS SNS for sending push notifications and I have used this article for the implementation http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx223MJB0XKV9RU/Mobile-token-management-with-Amazon-SNS

I am storing the token and the endpoints in the server for sending the push notifications, but the problem is with GCM when the reg_id gets changed and pervious reg_id is still active then the aws update the pervious endpoint with latest token, due to which I have got two endpoints with same reg_id and when I am sending the push notification then it is getting delivered twice.

I have searched everywhere but I am not able to find the solution, how do I update my server DB to delete the older endpoint.